# RegEx split match by keyword

Tags: regex, vba

I have this text:

```
     CTN1: CAIU3201968
     order No. 1900958
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000755   10     25       150     16 pcs/pallet    4 pallets      64,00 pce        77,25     4.944,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000753   10     25       100     20 pcs/pallet   16 pallets      320,00 pce       51,50    16.480,00
     CTN2: BSIU3070499
     order No. 1900958
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1007780   10     25       125     18 pcs/pallet    4 pallets      72,00 pce        64,38     4.635,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000751   10     25          60   40 pcs/pallet    2 pallets      80,00 pce        30,90     2.472,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000752   10     25          80   24 pcs/pallet    5 pallets      120,00 pce       41,20     4.944,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000753   10     25       100     20 pcs/pallet    3 pallets      60,00 pce        51,50     3.090,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1001526    8     20       100     36 pcs/pallet    5 pallets      180,00 pce       37,00     6.660,00
     CTN3: NYKU3708986
     order No. 1900958
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000751   10     25          60   40 pcs/pallet    9 pallets      360,00 pce       30,90    11.124,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1002452   10     25          75   24 pcs/pallet   11 pallets      264,00 pce       38,63    10.197,00
```

I need one RegEx match group per CTN, so Group one is:

```
    CTN1: CAIU3201968
     order No. 1900958
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
    1000755   10     25       150     16 pcs/pallet    4 pallets      64,00 pce        77,25     4.944,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
    1000753   10     25       100     20 pcs/pallet   16 pallets      320,00 pce       51,50    16.480,00
```

Group two:

```
CTN2: BSIU3070499
     order No. 1900958
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1007780   10     25       125     18 pcs/pallet    4 pallets      72,00 pce        64,38     4.635,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000751   10     25          60   40 pcs/pallet    2 pallets      80,00 pce        30,90     2.472,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000752   10     25          80   24 pcs/pallet    5 pallets      120,00 pce       41,20     4.944,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1000753   10     25       100     20 pcs/pallet    3 pallets      60,00 pce        51,50     3.090,00
     palisade, all sides middle picked, G603
1001526    8     20       100     36 pcs/pallet    5 pallets      180,00 pce       37,00     6.660,00
```

and so on.

What I habe try is this Regex:

```
CTN\d{1,2}:((.|\n)*)CTN\d{1,2}:
```

But with this I got only one group with everything and excluding the last group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

`\s*CTN\d{1,2}:[\S\s]*?(?=\s+CTN|\Z)`

https://regex101.com/r/ElfRn6/1

Comment: Thanks for your help: At the website it works, but not in my Code there the last CTN is missing. So  I have only 9 matches and not 10 like on the website, any idea? --> OK I got it, added the end statment after the last block and it works, thanks :)

Comment: @Zam89 Is it VBA in some MS Word? Then, watch out for `\Z`, ECMAScript does not support this construct

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative of using `[\S\s]*?` you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to match all the lines that do not start with the CTN pattern to limit the amount of backtracking.

```
^[^\S\r\n]*CTN\d{1,2}:.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*CTN\d).+)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars except a newline
- `CTN\d{1,2}:` Match CTN, 1 or 2 digits and a colon
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?![^\S\r\n]*CTN\d)` Negative lookahead, assert that the lines does not start with `CTN\d`
  - `.+` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat the group 0+ times

If there should be at least 1 line after CTN, you could repeat the last part 1+ times using `)+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p8ut7S/1)